# Project tracking/supervision

Tags: windows, project-management

I need to track/supervise the progress of a number of simple projects (about 50 at a time).

I need an overview of all current projects (active and pending). In short, I need to know to whom I have assigned a certain task, which project does that task belong in, what the task is and when that person is due to finish it. The software is for my use only – no team members involved and I don't need collaboration software.

The projects are linear (never more than one task pending and never more than one person working on it). The status of the projects changes daily, often several times per day.

The software MUST work exclusively offline (no web-based or cloud solutions – it's a deal breaker because all the data has to stay on site).

I need the ability to assign a customizable status to each (at least one, eg. the name of the person currently responsible for the project, but ideally there should be at least three customizeable fields). There should be the ability to set deadlines for the current task and the deadline for the project as a whole. More importantly, I need the ability to sort projects by status and deadline.

Unfinished projects are often pending because of third party inactivity, and it often takes months or even years to complete them. An automatic reminder to check in with those third parties would be nice, but not a requirement.

I've looked into aritable, among others, and it's quite close to what I need, but I can't use it because it's online.

So far I've made do with an Excel spreadsheet, and as the number of project increased I created an access database, but it's too cumbersome – I'm not good enough to make it do what I want, and do it efficiently. I'm dreaming of having an at a glance overview of everything I'm responsible for, easy to quickly update.

I'm looking for open source software for Win10.

If the data could be synchronized to Android, all the better (again, manual sync with a direct PC-to-phone connection, no clouds or the like), but it is not a requirement.

A calendar view would be nice, but it's not a requirement.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi. Note that some of the open source web solutions can be run on your laptop via a personal webserver e.g. xampp. Please see a couple in previous answer here:  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77887/purely-offline-personal-task-management-software-for-windows/77910#77910

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll look into it. For the time being, I've decided to use ToDoList (which is not the same as todoist).